# PySpark does undesired implicit type casting when using pivot. How to change the behavior to keep the original types?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types, pivot, query-optimization

Consider the following code snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

my_schema = StructType([
   StructField("key1", IntegerType(), False),
   StructField("key2", IntegerType(), False),
   StructField("value", ShortType(), False)
])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,1]],
    schema=my_schema
)

df2 = df1.groupby('key1').pivot('key2').sum('value')
```

Now the `df1` has the schema explicitly specified above:

```
key1:integer
key2:integer
value:short
```

However, `df1` has (unexpectedly) the schema:

```
key1:integer
1:long
2:long
```

I.e. the `short` has implicitly been cast to a `long`. I understand the reasoning for this may be that summing over many values could cause an overflow which the cast attempts to prevent. But I consider this undesirable, because in my application, the dataframe is both wide (many pivot columns) and long and I can reasonably assume the overflow won't happen so this leads to an unnecessary memory / computation time waste. I could obviously cast it back using instead something like:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('key1').pivot('key2').agg(F.sum('value').cast('short'))
```

or perhaps

```
df2 = (df1.groupby('key1').pivot('key2').sum('value')
       .withColumn('1', col('1').cast('short'))
       .withColumn('2', col('2').cast('short')))
```

but in my understanding, the `long` value is still going to exist at least in some intermediate state, wasting the computational resources anyway.

Is there a way to disable this implicit casting behavior?